# Como sacar porcentaje en Chartsjs usando vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, chart.js

Estoy usando *vue* a través de blade de PHP usando el vue-inline-template; uso *chart.js* mediante canvas. Estoy tratando de sacar el porcentaje para que se muestre en la gráfica. Pero, si calculo normalmente con `(4/100)*row.cantidad*100`, me da el porcentaje pero quisiera saber si hay una manera de mostrar el símbolo de porcentaje después de la cantidad.

```
  Vue.component('graficas', {
            data() {
                return {
                    regiones: [],
                    totalRegion: [],
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.loadPieGrafica()
            },
            methods: {
                loadPieGrafica: function(){
                this.$http.get('/calidad/GraficaNoConformidad/zona').then(response => {
                    
                    this.totalRegion = response.data.data.map(row => {
                        //return (4/100)*row.cantidad*100
                        return row.cantidad
                    })

                    this.regiones = _.uniq(response.data.data.map(row => row.region))

                    this.renderChart2()
                })
            },
            renderChart2(){
                var ctx = document.getElementById("pieGrafica");
                var pieGrafica = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                    labels: this.regiones, 
                    datasets: [{
                        data: this.totalRegion,
                        backgroundColor: ['#99FF99','#66CC99','#87CEEB','#BEBEBE'],
                        borderColor: ['#99FF99','#66CC99','#87CEEB','#BEBEBE'],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                 options: {
                    cutoutPercentage: 0,
                    responsive: true,
                   }
                });
            },
    
        const app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
        });
```

Comment: Si todo el texto está en negritas, nada resalta, pero se hace pesado de leer. Edité tu pregunta para corregir la mala ortografía :(, y además quité las negritas. Si quieres resaltar algo, coloca solo lo que quieras resaltar en negrita. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Pues solo con concatenar el símbolo seria mas que suficiente por ejemplo:

```
this.totalRegion = response.data.data.map(row => {
  return ((4/100)*row.cantidad*100) + ' %'
});
```